# 'Whereis python' gives me a bunch of directories that does not exist

Tags: python

i'm trying to find out where my python  installation is. I need it for IDE's and such. When I type

```
ask@garser:~$ which python3
/usr/bin/python3
```

which is a symbolic link to

```
/usr/bin/python3
```

So this seems like the correct placement.
But when I use whereis:

```
ask@garser:~$ whereis python3
python3: /usr/bin/python3 /usr/bin/python3.8 /usr/bin/python3.8-config /usr/lib/python3 /usr/lib/python3.8 /usr/lib/python3.9 /etc/python3 /etc/python3.8 /usr/local/lib/python3.8 /usr/include/python3.8 /usr/share/python3 /usr/share/man/man1/python3.1.gz
```

Which gives me a lot of results.

some of them don't even exist

Comment: Which paths didn't exist?

Answer (score 0):

You can see some details about the paths when run `python3 --help` on the terminal.

Such as:

```
PYTHONSTARTUP: file executed on interactive startup (no default)
PYTHONPATH   : ':'-separated list of directories prefixed to the
               default module search path.  The result is sys.path.
PYTHONHOME   : alternate <prefix> directory (or <prefix>:<exec_prefix>).
               The default module search path uses <prefix>/lib/pythonX.X.
PYTHONPYCACHEPREFIX: root directory for bytecode cache (pyc) files.
```